# ExtJS4 - choose card in card layout based on data in model

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

Is there a way to automatically select a card in card layout when the record is loaded?

I want to have multiple mutually exclusive field-groups in a form. I want to switch between them automatically based on a value in the model. Is it possible with the card layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing automatic exists as far as I know. You will have to manually show/hide them based on the information you loaded in the controller.

Comment: That means that in order to bind the data, I'd have to take special care of the fields in each card?

Comment: Yes. You can combine fields into fieldsets and hide/show them in groups